# Android change screen tint

Tags: android, android-widget, tint

I want to create an app that tints the entire android screen a certain color. The tint or color overlay would be global. Similar to [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netmanslab.sa&hl=en). How would I even do this? Would it be a widget? Code samples appreciated!

Comment: Any luck? I have the same need. Would like to hear if you were able to find a solution.